# how to have multiple ASP.NET MVC projects in a solution that merge to form a single web

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

we have a web application(asp.net mvc3) distributed to many clients. most of the controllers and views are same for all clients, but there are some controllers and views which are customized to each client.
currently we are duplicating the solution for each client, with customized controllers and views.
but by this way we are facing a problem that when we change a controller that is common to all clients, we usually have to modify it in each solution.
i m looking for some way to have a common mvc project contains common controllers and views, and for customized controllers i would like to have different mvc projects, all placed into the same solution.
for e.g

```
myApplication.web.ui.Core    => contains common controllers.
myApplication.web.ui.Client1  => contains client 1 custom controllers.
myApplication.web.ui.Client2   => contains client 2 custom controllers.
```

so when i need to build for client 1 , i will set myApplication.web.ui.Client1 as startup project, and when i need to build for client 2 i will set myApplication.web.ui.Client2 as startup project.

Answer (score 0):

You could define areas in your main App. For each area, you can either have the standard area or a complete MVC project.

Comment: i donot want to do it using areas.